# how to plot a mixed graph in R?

Tags: r, graphs

How can I plot a mixed graph in R?

I have used this but doesn't work (in bnlearn he calls 'arc' to a directed edge and 'edge' to an undirected edge):

```
library(bnlearn)
dag=empty.graph(nodes = c("E", "F"))
graphviz.plot(dag)
dag = set.edge(dag, from = "E", to = "F")
dag = set.arc(dag, to = "E", from = "F")
graphviz.plot(dag)
```

As specified in the documentation https://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/arcops.html it will overwrite the arc...
(Note that in bnlearn library he calls 'arc' to a directed edge and 'edge' to an undirected edge)

I want to be able to plot a mixed graph like:

[image]

(arc (directed edge) between E and F, also edge (undirected edge) **at the same time**).

(If R cannot do it, is there any other easy tool I could use?, my goal is just to plot)

edit: I just realized thatBayesian Networks need to be acyclic by definition, so I guess I am hopeless with the bnlearn library...

Comment: I know this can be done with the tikz package for LaTeX, but that's probably too far outside your current stack...